# Setting cookie for browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookiestore

I am currently using a cookie to store the width of the screen, but I want to know the width of the browser on each page refresh.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['screenwidth'])) 
{
    return "<script>
        if (window.outerWidth) {
            document.cookie='screenwidth='+window.outerWidth+'; path=/';location.reload(true);
        } else {
            document.cookie='screenwidth='+document.documentElement.clientWidth+'; path=/';location.reload(true);
        }
    </script>";
}
```

This is what I currently have. Is there a way to set the width with jQuery? I am much more familiar with this.
Also, how would I go about setting the width with JavaScript?

Comment: you can also set cookies from jQuery..

Comment: why dont you just use `$(window).width()`?

Answer (score 0):

Download [**jQuery.Cookies**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) first.

Use it as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var checkCookie = $.cookie("browser_width");
        if (checkCookie != "")
        {
            alert(checkCookie);
        }
        else
        {
            $.cookie("browser_width", CODEFORBROWSERWIDTH);
        }
    });

</script>
```